# The method moveCamera(CameraUpdate) in the type GoogleMap is not applicable for the arguments (CameraUpdate,

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to craete my fist Google map Project I did all steps on this page 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
so far  I run the Project and I can see the map but then I tried to modify my `MainActivity` class to this class code which I copied and pasted from the the link above:

**Code:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        //At this line I am getting the error below.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney), 10);
    }
}
```

but I am getting this error. How can I move the camera?

> The method moveCamera(CameraUpdate) in the type GoogleMap is not applicable for the arguments (CameraUpdate, 
>    int)

Answer (score 2):

It's an doc error, you can do:

Just delete the `10` in the end such that:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
```

Or I think the int `10` stands for zoom, so change it as follows:

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 10));
```

At this point you should be good to go.